# Casio CDP-235r recorded playback

Tags: multitrack

I have a Casio CDP-235R. It can record 6 tracks, and the first can record layered sounds. I recorded the first track (elec. piano with music box), then used other sounds for the remaining tracks (bass, drums, flute, etc.). During playback, I can select each track to mute and unmute it during the playback. This works for all except the layered track, where it only mutes one layer of the track (only mutes the elec. piano but music box would still play). Is there a way to mute both layers of track 1? Or is the second layer of track 1 always unmutable?

Comment: What do the instructions tell you?

Comment: The instruction manual doesn’t get that detailed